# Synonym of many, multitude, etc., but starting with ph-

Tags: pronunciation, synonyms

I have been working on my tongue, but not able to get it. The word means many, multiple, multitude and so on. The closest that my brain can think is something rhyming with "**phelanthra**".

A phrase might be, "*phelanthra* of objects".

Answer (score 10):

I think the word you want is ***plethora***, meaning an 'over-abundance'. (Oxford Dictionaries).

Answer (score 5):

Usually, when I have just a vague memory of the correct spelling of an unusual word I type the following on Google, e.g.:

```
define: plhelanthra
```

Dependending on how close the word is to the correct spelling, I usually get the one I was looking for, in this case, it presented the correct word in the 2nd suggestion:

**pleth·o·ra**

ˈpleTHərə

noun

1. a large or excessive amount of (something).
   "a plethora of committees and subcommittees"
   *synonyms: excess, overabundance, superabundance, surplus, glut, superfluity, surfeit, profusion;*